# Moment Generating Function - Find K

Tags: random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Given:

$M_x(w) = K/(2-w)$

Find $K$.

That is all what we are given. How exactly do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that, by definition of a moment generating function, $$M_X(w)=E(\exp(wX)), w \in \mathbb R.$$ In particular, we have for $w=0:$ $M_X(0)=E(\exp(0))=E(1)=1.$ (Regarless of what's the random variable $X$ and its moment generating function $M_X$)

What does this imply for $M_X(w)=K/(2-w)$?

Comment: Does it mean (K/2) = 1, thus K = 2?

Comment: The original problem is (2-w), not (w-2).

Comment: @Sonny: My bad. Thanks for pointing this out! And yes, $K=2$.